# How do I make a MySQL query on a comma-separated field in Joomla 3?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I'm trying to make a MySQL query in Joomla 3 module to find the rows that contain a specific id value in the `lexicon` column. All fields are strings of comma-separated integers from multi-select elements made in `Component Creator`. I'm not used to working with Joomla so maybe that's the reason why I `$results` turns up as empty array `[]` in this code.
Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
/*
Example on table: tab__lexi

id  | lexicon     | dog     | cat
____|_____________|_________|_________
1   | 1,2         | 3,8     | 4
2   | 5,6,9       | 3,2     | 1,3,4,5 
*/
 

$lexiId=5;
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('dog', 'cat')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__lexi'));
$query->where($db->quote($lexiId) . ' IN ('. $db->quoteName('lexicon').')');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$res=json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Try to switch your code from
$query->where($db->quote($lexiId) . ' IN ('. $db->quoteName('lexicon').')');

To

$query->where( $db->quoteName('lexicon') . ' IN ('. $db->quote($lexiId).')');

So it would generate a query like this: SELECT dog, cat FROM lexi WHERE lixicon IN (5);

But if your data in lexicon column is stored in a single row than you can't use IN operator but you could use LIKE (which will slow down your performance on large data set)

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion Igor, but that doesn work.

Comment: Using LIKE doesn work too. The data is shown in phpMyAdmin as comma seperated strings like shown in the example.

Comment: Have you tried running you script like this:
SELECT dog, cat FROM lexi WHERE lexicon LIKE "%YOUR_VALUE_HERE%"; ?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: You must not use `LIKE` for your task because it can very easily provide incorrect results (e.g. search for 1 and match 11).  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MoWmKPuzTrrC3DQJsiX35/6 You should use FIND_IN_SET() if you are not going to refactor your schema to something more "normal". This page is dangerous because it is teaching researchers incorrect programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch your code from

`$query->where($db->quote($lexiId) . ' IN ('. $db->quoteName('lexicon').')');`

To

`$query->where( $db->quoteName('lexicon') . ' IN ('. $db->quote($lexiId).')');`

So it would generate a query like this:

`SELECT dog, cat FROM lexi WHERE lixicon IN (5);`

But if your data in lexicon column is stored in a single row than you can't use IN operator but you could use LIKE (which will slow down your performance on large data set)

SQL Like example

```
SELECT dog, cat FROM lexi WHERE lexicon LIKE "%YOUR_VALUE_HERE%";
```

Comment: If you are able to provide Joomla support, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange (We can always use more members who like to help others.)

Comment: Truth is, neither of your recommendations should be used by the OP or developers.  Please see my demo link comment under the question.